# YouTube analytics api data from service account

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How to get youtube analytics api data from aws cloud?

I have setup a project in Google cloud console and configured oauth authentication and able to get the response from the YouTube Analytics api but it asks for user consent which means I manually have to click on allow access to the project.

I plan to run my script in cloud environment in aws lambda and hence would like to avoid the user consent.

I am trying to see if I can setup service account to achive this and the YouTube documentation says it doesn't support service account.

Does it apply for all the YouTube apis or only the Analytics api?

Has any one tried to use the YouTube data api or YouTube analytics api from aws cloud